# Не закрывается блок при нажатии мимо блока на IPAD

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, вёрстка

есть проблема на устройстве Ipad, не закрывается блок при клике мимо него, вот верстка на хостинге http://questbox7.liemstar.ru
Вот скриншот на котором объяснения http://joxi.ru/Q2KzQYNt4jXGEm

Я использую для закрытие блока при клике мимо него следующий код

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
        if (!$(e.target).closest(".search").length) {
            $('.search__dropdown').slideUp(200);
        }
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
```